# Python: logic error in calculating a year (leap)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I this code which is suppose to return a list with the closest leap year of a list of years.

For example: calling the function with `[1995 1750 2018]` should return

`1996 1748 2016`

Which it does for that set of numbers.

The problem I am having is that when a leap year is in the input for example `2008` it does not give me back the closest leap year to `2008`. I get back `2008`.

Any suggestions as to how I can modify the code to make it work?

code

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False


    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
            leap = True

    return leap


major_b = []
major_f = []
newLst = []


def year_forward(yearBounds):

    for item in yearBounds:
        counter = 0

        while not is_leap(item):
            item = item + 1
            counter += 1


         major_f.append([item, counter])
    return major_f


def year_backward(yearBounds):

    for item in yearBounds:
        counter = 0
        while not is_leap(item):
            item = item - 1
            counter -= 1


        major_b.append([item,counter])

    return major_b






def findLastLeapYears(yearBounds):

    forward =  year_forward(yearBounds)
    backward = year_backward(yearBounds)



    counter = 0
    for item in forward:
        if abs(item[1]) < abs(backward[counter][1]):
            newLst.append (str(item[0]))
            counter+=1
        elif abs(item[1]) == abs(backward[counter][1]):
            if item[0] < backward[counter][0]:
                newLst.append (str(item[0]))
                counter += 1
            else:
                newLst.append (str(backward[counter][0]))
                counter += 1

        else:
            newLst.append (str(backward[counter][0]))
            counter+=1

    return newLst
```

Comment: What's the correct answer? 2008 is a leap year so the "nearest" leap year being that year seems reasonable. The choice of '04 or '12 would be pretty arbitrary. As a side note, it seems like you could do this pretty simply with just a modulo. Once you've got your `%4` answer you can use addition or subtraction to get to the nearest leap year with a little bit of comparison logic to decide which direction is "nearest".

Comment: The closest leap year to a leap year is itself.

Comment: Well, it should be 2004. 2012 is also 4 years away but the earlier date is what is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd avoid trying to roll your own leap year detection code. Use `calendar.isleap` to determine whether a year is a leap year or not.

Then go in a loop, like this:

```
    import calendar    
    def find_nearest_leap(year):
        offset = 1
        while True:
           if calendar.isleap(year - offset):
               return year - offset
           if calendar.isleap(year + offset):
               return year + offset
           offset += 1
```

To find the list of nearest leap years for a list of values, do this:

```
nearest_leap_years = [find_nearest_leap(year) for year in years]
```

Where `years` is the list of years you are interested in.

I'm also assuming the nearest leap year isn't the year itself, which seems to be a constraint of the problem...

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is a homework question and the immediate feedback will be something along the lines of, "We can't use this library." Good answer, though!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Except it doesn't solve OP's problem

Comment: whoops - yes - I misread the question. I thought they were asking for the closest leap year to a given year.

Comment: I'm missing something -- why doesn't this solve the issue?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I actually wrote code. I am just seeking clarification. Not like I am coming here asking for a handout. Come on man!

Comment: They had a list - I've added the list

Comment: @NicoleFoster No problems and HW questions are accepted. It's just a normal thing to be forbidden to use built-in stuff like this. Your question is fine.

Comment: @Owen I really like your solution, I personally would use itertools's count so you wouldn't have to change the offset manually.

Comment: A minor comment, the OP said that in case of a _leap year_ is the input, it should return the previous one. It might be better to swap the position of the `if`s.

Comment: Good point MaLiN and Marco. Marco I've updated to your suggestion.

Comment: @Owen Thank you but do you see anyway my code could work or its just irredeemable?

Comment: @NicoleFoster your code could work fine, you just need to update it to return the previous leap year if the input is a leap year